# Plotting multiple grouped scatter graphs with regression lines on the same axes

Tags: excel, regression, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a data vis which is essentially a scattergraph.

A snip of the data looks like this:

| Location | Year | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1990 | 48.3973 | 1377.85863 |
| Afghanistan | 2020 | 65.432 | 620.40751 |
| Albania | 1990 | 76.4334 | 32.87494 |
| Albania | 2020 | 79.6756 | 8.27645 |
| Algeria | 1990 | 68.5167 | 205.81979 |
| Algeria | 2020 | 75.9125 | 77.69479 |
| Angola | 1990 | 82.6756 | 1101.50579 |
| Angola | 2020 | 83.1922 | 221.90649 |
| Antigua and Barbuda | 1990 | 73.6497 | 58.0267 |
| Antigua and Barbuda | 2020 | 80.7452 | 21.24795 |
| Argentina | 1990 | 75.9699 | 87.81427 |
| Argentina | 2020 | 81.3155 | 44.90008 |

That is, each country has a pair of points.  I'd like to plot A against B, and then ideally have each country's pair of points (in a perfect world) in a different colour (ideally with labels, showing which country they are and which year).

I then would like to plot a regression line of all the 1990 points, and a regression line on the same axes of the 2020 points.

In Excel would be ideal, but I could potentially use something else if it would be more appropriate.  Any help would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to other options, I thought I can answer your question in python, if that's ok. Here's how you can do it with seaborn, a nice data visualization package that has a lot of helpful functions for statistics and ML.

First, to get you started with python, I would recommend [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/), as their installation already includes a tonne of nice packages which are all compatible with each other.

After getting acquainted, you can import the following packages for the example:

```
import seaborn as sns # nice plotting
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # package also for plottingm the above line is a magic command to define the backend
import pandas as pd # for data handling
```

I defined the data without Afghanistan for now, as it seems to be a bad outlier that negatively affects the regression models, I'll show that at the end. For now, here are the results without AFG:

```
data = {
    'Location': ['Albania', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Algeria', 'Angola', 'Angola', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Argentina', 'Argentina'],
    'Year': [1990, 2020, 1990, 2020, 1990, 2020, 1990, 2020, 1990, 2020],
    'A': [76.4334, 79.6756, 68.5167, 75.9125, 82.6756, 83.1922, 73.6497, 80.7452, 75.9699, 81.3155],
    'B': [32.87494, 8.27645, 205.81979, 77.69479, 1101.50579, 221.90649, 58.0267, 21.24795, 87.81427, 44.90008]
} # define the data without afghanistan
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # generate dataframe
plt.figure() # figure
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='A', y='B', hue='Location', style='Year') # scatter plot the data, changing style for year and colour with country
sns.regplot(data=df[df['Year'] == 1990], x='A', y='B', scatter=False, color='blue') # plot model for 1990
sns.regplot(data=df[df['Year'] == 2020], x='A', y='B', scatter=False, color='orange') # plot model for 2000
plt.grid() # add grid
plt.legend(loc = "lower right", ncols = 3) # and legend
```

This leads to the following plot:

[image: regression plot without AFG]

Of course, if you have the data in a better way, you can use `pd.read_excel()` or `pd.read_csv()` to get the data from saved files.

Check the data with Afghanistan here:

[image: Plots with AFG]

As you see, the regression primarily captures the variance found between AFG and the other groups. This can be solves, for example, by using [robust regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression) instead.

I hope this answer encourages you to start learning python and doing this. The advantage would be that there are a lot of resources these days to get started and to even master python. Also, chatGPT can help you get started (you will come back complaining about it anyway ;) )